# why a variable declare outside of the function does not recognize by the function

Tags: javascript, scope

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

function myFunction(){
   alert(input);

}

window.onload = function(){
var input = "hello";
    myFunction();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my code why it doesn't alert `hello`?

Comment: You should read about variable scope in JS.

Comment: The `input` variable is inside the `window.onload` function, which makes it inaccessible  from outside.

Comment: What made you think it should be recognized? Any tutorial that misguided you?

Comment: @ShadowWizard nope i dont know it is a variable scope problem initially

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `input` within `myFunction` refers to a global variable, but the `input` within the `onload` is a local variable.

Try passing the input as a parameter to `myFunction`:

```
function myFunction(input){
   alert(input);
}

window.onload = function(){
    var input = "hello";
    myFunction(input);
}
```

Or declare `input` as a global variable and remove the `var` from within the event handler:

```
var input;

function myFunction(){
   alert();
}

window.onload = function(){
    input = "hello";
    myFunction();
}
```

<sup>Note that declaring `input` outside of these functions isn't necessary (except in strict mode), but it's generally good practice.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

input is not a global variable in your case, you can't access it through the other function, is scoped to the anonymous function bound to onload event.

If you want to access it like if it's a setting, you must declare it outside of any function OR you must declare it without var OR you must declare it with window.input. In any case, I won't suggest you to use any of the mentioned feature unless the variable is actually something that should be shared across all your application.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of input is restricted to the window.load function()

if you want to access the input from multiple functions make it a global variable.

```
<script>
var input = "";

function myFunction(){
   alert(input);

}

window.onload = function(){
    input = "hello";
    myFunction();
}
</script>
```

or passed the input as paramete to the function

```
<script>

function myFunction(var input){
   alert(input);

}

window.onload = function(){
var input = "hello";
    myFunction(input);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to make it "work" that wasn't mentioned yet is having both the variable and the function part of the `onload` method:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var input = "hello";
    function myFunction(){
        alert(input);
    }

    myFunction();
}
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/57Bbu/).